# arab digits with arabtex

Tags: arabtex

I'm using `arabtex`, with `latex` or `pdflatex`.

In my documents I use only arabic digits: 1 2 3 ...

But `arabtex` display the digits in indian (not arabic).

I used to use `\textLR{}` to get the numbering that I want, but this method became tiring when I deal with a big document with lot of numbers inside.

The question is: is there a way to set the arabic digits definitively for all the document?

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,arabic]{babel}

\begin{document}

الأرقام الهندية: 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
\textLR{ These are indian digits.}

الأرقام العربية :
\textLR{
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
}\\
 \textLR{These are arab digits that I want but without the cmd textLR.}
\end{document}
```